# How to use Vec2w in Opencv Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I have this part of code working in C++

```
Mat mapFrame5(Size(321,262), CV_16UC2);
for (int y = 0; y < mapFrame5.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < mapFrame5.cols; x++) {
        mapFrame5.at<Vec2w>(y, x) = Vec2w(y, x);
        cout<<mapFrame5.at<Vec2w>(y,x);
    }
}
```

I have a hard time finding if there is equivalent of this expression in Python:

```
mapFrame5.at<Vec2w>(y, x) = Vec2w(y, x);
```

I tried following as suggested:

```
testArr2 = np.zeros([262,321], np.uint16)

y,yy = 0,0
byteCount = 0
while yy < 262:
    x,xx = 0,0
    while xx < 321:
        testArr2[yy,xx] = [yy,xx]
        xx+=1
        x+=1        
        byteCount+=1
    yy+=1
    y+=1
```

But it gives me only this error:

```
builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'
```

For clearence I'm trying to save y,x values to little endian binary file.

Example:

y = 0

0 0 0 1 0 2 0 3 ... 0 320

y = 261

261 0 261 1 261 2 ... 261 320

C++ file gives me exacly 336408 bytes

Comment: It could help if you'd explain in plain words what do you want to achieve with your expression for non C++ readers...

Comment: opencv `Mat` in python are just numpy arrays. You code can just be `mapFrame5[y,x] = [y,x]` in python.

Comment: @QuangHoang Edited post, I can't get your solution to work

Comment: You need to make the array 2 channel - `np.zeros([262,321,2], np.uint16)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive approach would be to just transcribe the algorithm to Python:

```py
def gen_grid_1(rows, cols):
    result = np.zeros((rows, cols, 2), np.uint16)
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            result[r,c,:] = [r, c]
    return result
```

Example output for 3 rows and 5 columns:

```py
[[[0 0]
  [0 1]
  [0 2]
  [0 3]
  [0 4]]

 [[1 0]
  [1 1]
  [1 2]
  [1 3]
  [1 4]]

 [[2 0]
  [2 1]
  [2 2]
  [2 3]
  [2 4]]]
```

However, this approach has a serious drawback -- it will be very slow, due to Python interpreter overhead -- for your example 321x262 array, this takes almost 1 second to complete.

---

A better approach is to restate the goal of the algorithm, and reimplement using optimized functions provided by Numpy.

What we want to generate is a 2 channel array of 16-bit unsigned integers, where the first channel of each element holds its row index, and the second channel holds the column index.

This sounds very close to what the [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) function does: "Return coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors."

The only catch is that it returns 2 individual arrays. We can simply use [`numpy.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to combine them into one with the channels in desired order.

```py
def gen_grid_2(rows, cols):
    cc, rr = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols, dtype=np.uint16), np.arange(rows, dtype=np.uint16))
    return np.dstack([rr,cc])
```

The output of this function is identical to the first, but it runs in approx. 2 milliseconds (i.e. ~500x faster than the naive approach).

---

Full script with timing comparisons:

```py
import numpy as np

ROWS = 262
COLS = 321

def gen_grid_1(rows, cols):
    result = np.zeros((rows, cols, 2), np.uint16)
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            result[r,c,:] = [r, c]
    return result

def gen_grid_2(rows, cols):
    cc, rr = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols, dtype=np.uint16), np.arange(rows, dtype=np.uint16))
    return np.dstack([rr,cc])


assert(np.array_equal(gen_grid_1(ROWS, COLS), gen_grid_2(ROWS, COLS)))


import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('r1 = gen_grid_1(ROWS, COLS)'
    , number=10
    , setup="from __main__ import gen_grid_1, ROWS, COLS"))
print(timeit.timeit('r1 = gen_grid_2(ROWS, COLS)'
    , number=10
    , setup="from __main__ import gen_grid_2, ROWS, COLS"))
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I though so there may be a numpy function for it.